# How to restore cassandra snapshot on a new single node cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I have done a snapshot of one of the key space which has 10 column family. There are 10 snapshot folder under each of column family folder.i want to restore these snapshot in one the development server (single node).

How can i easily restore it on a development using sstanbleloader

Dev node is on a Windows 2012 Standard Server
Prod is on a Windows 2012 Ent.Edition Server

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use sstableloader in this case. I think the most straightforward method would be the "Node restart method" described [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html).

There are plenty of details in the docs, but basically: stop the node, remove data files from data directories, and replace with snapshot files.

Comment: Thanks Adam , that's what i did before i posted the question.Could you help me understand when should i use sstableloader

Comment: (1) loading external data (written into SSTable format) into a cluster; (2) when loading data into a cluster with different node count/replication settings;
I would always prefer direct placement of the files if they're already on the nodes and replication will be the same.